# External Hard disk not workng on windows after I formatted it on Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, windows, external-hdd

I formatted my Western Digital 500 Gb hard disk on Ubuntu 10.4 and now I want to use it on Windows 7 but it cannot detect it.

I formatted it with FAT(applicable to all) option.

I tried to Google this problem a bit and as suggested by one of the site i tried to format this drive with NTFS. Still windows cannot detect it.

Drives in windows 7 is not a problem because I tried a different usb drive on it and it works.

I can see the led of the drive glow when I connect it and I can also see remove drive safely option in lower right corner, but i cannot see any option in "my computer" to access the hard disk.

I am new to Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to format my HDD using "diskpart" utility available on widows7. It is working now.

Just run "diskpart" on command-promt on diskpart select your HDD and run following commands:

```
CLEAN
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY 
SELECT PARTITION 1
ACTIVE
FORMAT FS=FAT32 QUICK
ASSIGN
EXIT
```